# Parsing JSON returned by URLLoader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using a URLLoader and URLRequest to make a call to youtube's api. The return is formatted as json and looks like the following: http://pastebin.com/WxPS9NCB.

I'm trying to capture the "href" value located on line 42 in the above pastebin. But the code I have isn't working.

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(apiURL));
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event) {
        var json:Object = e.target.data;
        var href:String = json.link[0].href;
        trace(href);
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash does not parse JSON automatically. Use AS3 core libs JSON parser (https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib)

And replace `var json:Object = e.target.data;` with `var json:Object = JSON.decode(e.target.data);`

EDIT:
After a cursory glance at the JSON file you should use `json.feed.link[0].href` to access the data you are looking for.

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at Function/<anonymous>() error.

Comment: Hard to say what the issue might be - run it through debug mode and see what it chokes on.

Comment: My bad. Had the path wrong. It was json.feed.entry[0].link[0].href. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For extra niceness try the JSONObject class. http://manishjethani.com/archives/2008/08/25/jsonobject-for-reading-and-writing-json-in-actionscript

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(apiURL));

urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event) {
        var json:Object = e.target.data;
        var href:String = json.link[0].href;
        trace(href);
});
```

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. I get Error #1069: Property link not found on String and there is no default value.